# Quarkus Lambda migration to Java 21

Tags: java, gradle, lambda, quarkus

I have a quarkus gradle java 11 project. It is an aws lambda. To that, I am using quarkus-amazon-lambda.

My boss decided to update the code from java 11 to java 21. I installed java 21 on my machine and updated gradle version.

I build my project and run the command *"sam local invoke --template build/sam.jvm.yaml --event payload.json -d 5005"* to run the lambda locally.

When I run the project the following error is thrown **"MailNotifyRequest has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 65.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0"**.

Investigating I saw that every time that I build the application a file named sam.jvm.yaml is generated and in the the runtime is set as java11. When I run the sam command that I mentioned above a docker container based in an image using the java 11 is built. Could it be the root of the error? If yes, how can I solve it? How do I set up to a java 21 image to be used? How do I set the file sam.jvm.yaml to use java21 as runtime?

Curiosity question: where sam.jvm.yaml is defined to be created?

Sorry if I made stupid questions, just a 6 month junior here.

Comment: Your image will run with whatever JDK is present on the was base image. The file you mention defines the JDK for local testing. See https://quarkus.io/guides/aws-lambda